# iPad using scrollTop with fixed navigation not functioning properly. Only works first time

Tags: jquery, ipad, scrolltop

I am developing a single page site with vertical scroll for navigation. I have a fixed position nav bar and my scrolling content is supposed to go up and down while being floated right of the navigation. Here is a preview link: http://mistersaisho.com/actioncreations/pageSlider/

The problem is that it works perfectly fine in firefox, safari and chrome. When I view it on an Ipad, the first time I select a nav item, the scroll works perfectly. As soon as it completes, all the click functionality from my nav is not working, even the ones that are not controlling the slider content.

I do not get the error when I am animating a different property like marginTop, that will not work in my project because I also need to be able to navigate throughout the site by using the page scroller.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I was testing on the simulator iOS5, everything seems to work, are you using iOS4? Edit: Nvm I answered my own question, problem on iOS 4 only

Comment: can you post some relative code, or create a simple example so we can test it?

Comment: This worked for me [ios fixed positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10439425/1435376)

Answer (score 0):

ipads and iphones dont seem to update their scrollTop position after animating unless you use you finger to jiggle the scroll position after animating. need to find a way to force the ipad to recognise its scroll position. maybe try this instead of scrollTop; window.pageYOffset.

Comment: This won't work on `IPAD4/IOS7`. and sadly couldn't find any other options to derermine the `scrollTop` during animation yet

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478853/43217