# Website with Javascript bug on my Apple devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

Hello everyone (sorry my English is not perfect), 
I make a website with JavaScript (jQuery) but I have one line not working on my **iPhone** and my **iPad**.

I write: ***window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);***

It's better on my website but on my devices its not running.

Would you know a functional equivalent of this function?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already look at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416977/scrollto-with-ipad-and-fixed-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile Safari bug on fixed positioned button after scrollTop programmatically changed...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752220/mobile-safari-bug-on-fixed-positioned-button-after-scrolltop-programmatically-ch)

Comment: I tried but it does not have to solve my problem