# iPhone: fixed div sticks in the middle of the page when coming back by "history.back(-1)"

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari, css-position

Having a problem with fixed div using iPhone. I know that in iOS 5 the functionality for `position:fixed` has been added. My div is positioned at the top of the screen and behave pretty good, anyway, there are some bugs during scrolling.

But what *actually* makes me angry - it is the position of this div after coming back to the current page clicking on `javascript:history.back(-1)` link. The fixed div sticks in the middle of a screen. When I try to scrool, it jumps back on the right position.

Is there any cure for the bug?

PS. Sometimes the div is completely not visible after returning by `history:back` function. It shows up after scrolling. It seems to me a bit the same problem.

```
<div class='rlm fixed rlm-zindex'>
  <a href='http://webiste.com/' target='_new'>
    <img src='banner-960.png' class='jqwatch' border=0 />
  </a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div.rlm {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            border-bottom: solid 1px;
        }

div.rlm img {
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

.fixed { position: fixed; }
.rlm-zindex { z-index: 5; }
```

Comment: Can you provide code example?

Comment: Sure. I've added examples in the question text.

Comment: I have tested in Safari (desktop), and I cannot reproduce the problem. Is it reproducible only with iPhone?

Comment: I'm sorry of letting you misunderstand my question. I meant Safari on iPhone. I've corrected the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems to [be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282149/jquery-mobile-fixed-footer-ios-web-view-and-scrolltop-issue) [a](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/1) [Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752220/mobile-safari-bug-on-fixed-positioned-button-after-scrolltop-programmatically-ch)!

There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439425/22470), but you have to change the scrollto into onload or similar...