# iPad and parallax effect

Tags: jquery, css, html, parallax

I am having issues with a parallax effect on the iPad, I don't need it to fully function, I know it's not going to scroll right, but for some reason, all the backgrounds are off, and the position fixed is not setting correctly. Also at some points my position fixed nav the links aren't clickable, although they have a high enough z-index.

If I take out the position fixed on the backgrounds, I see them all, but they are shifted too far to the left with a huge gap on the right. Where am I going wrong? This is my first attempt at this effect, I got it working in IE 7 + Chrome and Firefox fine.

Here it the link: http://inrekor.awcbits.com/

Comment: The following is a work around for the issue where links in the fixed position element lose their interactivity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752220/mobile-safari-bug-on-fixed-positioned-button-after-scrolltop-programmatically-ch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also working on a parallax and have realized that it just doesn't work on iOS devices. Probably the same reason the Nike Better World parallax site is static images when viewed on mobile.

This has been addressed by someone else already and might help: [CSS "position: fixed;" on iPad/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889601/css-position-fixed-into-ipad-iphone)